# Why (and how) do "implicit" references to the FROM table cause the return of false results in this query?

Tags: t-sql, ssms

The purpose of my query is to link DateTimeIn and DateTimeOut entries between two tables by the RegistrationNumber. (The data is from a parking utilisation survey...)

I tried a join first, but it couldn't handle the complexity. E.g., a vehicle may have a DateTimeOut (it exited the parking area), but no DateTimeIn (it never parked, maybe because the bays were all occupied). Also, I have to ensure that the first DateTimeIn gets linked to the earliest DateTimeOut and that each DateTime is linked to only once.

The following "nested query" seemed to get the job done, but it returned false positive results. I have no idea how these got generated. Even if there wasn't a DateTimeOut for a RegistrationNumber, one was returned. Weirdly, after making all the references to the tables explicit, these false positives were eliminated.

```
-- Implicit reference to the second table (causes false positives):

SELECT
    RegistrationNumber,
    DateTimeIn,
    (SELECT MIN(O.DateTimeOut) FROM HobieBeachVehiclesOut O WHERE O.RegistrationNumber = RegistrationNumber AND O.DateTimeOut > DateTimeIn) AS DateTimeOut
FROM HobieBeachVehiclesIn
ORDER BY DateTimeIn, RegistrationNumber

-- Explicit references all round (no glaring errors):

SELECT
    RegistrationNumber,
    DateTimeIn,
    (SELECT MIN(O.DateTimeOut) FROM HobieBeachVehiclesOut O WHERE O.RegistrationNumber = A.RegistrationNumber AND O.DateTimeOut > A.DateTimeIn) AS DateTimeOut
FROM HobieBeachVehiclesIn A
ORDER BY DateTimeIn, RegistrationNumber
```

**Results:**

```
-- Implicit reference to the second table (causes false positives):

JHB 036 03/05/2019 00:09:00 03/05/2019 06:08:00
FNB 559 03/05/2019 06:00:00 03/05/2019 06:08:00
HGB 115 03/05/2019 06:05:00 03/05/2019 06:08:00

-- Explicit references all round (no glaring errors):

JHB 036 03/05/2019 00:09:00 NULL
FNB 559 03/05/2019 06:00:00 03/05/2019 06:48:00
HGB 115 03/05/2019 06:05:00 03/05/2019 07:53:00
```

The errors are clear and now, with the second glance, even more peculiar. Where would this DateTimeOut come from? And why can't the query handle the "implicit reference" to dbo.HobieBeachVehiclesIn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in a query, when you do not alias your column, the alias is assumed. The assumed alias is any table that has the column you are using. This works fine and you will only get an error if there is more than one table in your query with the same column... at which point you need to alias.

So in your first query with the RegistrationNumber not aliased, the RegistrationNumber column is assumed to come from the only table in the query... the one aliased "O". This is the same as writing " WHERE RegistrationNumber = RegistrationNumber " in your subquery.

To write a correlated subquery (which is what you have... a subquery that that refers to a column outside of itself) you MUST include the alias of the outer query. SQL, as I stated, will assume an alias if no alias is given, but it will only assume a table WITHIN the same query. It will not look outside for an assumed table alias.

Comment: The answer seems so obvious in retrospect! How could I expect the subquery to refer to a table that wasn't revealed to it?! Probably the typography - not seeing that as a whole query on its own or something... But I understand now. Thank you for the eye-opener.